# Backbone.View.setElement work unexpected

Tags: backbone.js

An simple [demo](http://jsbin.com/lojotekepi/1/):

```
    var PersonListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addOne);
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.addAll);
        },
        addOne: function (model) {
            var subView = new PersonItemView({model: model});
            $(this.el).append(subView.render().el);
        },
        addAll: function () {
            $(this.el).empty();
            this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
        },
        render: function () {
            this.addAll();
            return this;
        }
    });
    var PersonItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template($('#tpl_person_item').html()),
        initialize: function () {
            this.listenTo(this.model, 'remove', this.remove);
            this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
        },
        render: function () {
            console.info("render person:" + this.model.get("name"));
            var el = $(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            this.setElement(el);
            return this;
        }
    });

    var p = new Person({name: 'name1'});
    var ps = new PersonList();
    ps.add(p);
    new PersonListView({
        el: $("#list"),
        collection: ps
    }).render();
    setTimeout(function () {
        p.set("name", "new name")
    }, 5000);
```

As shown, I bind the `change` event of the model to the view by:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
```

However though the `render` method is called, the element are not updated to the page.

It seems that the `setElement` does not add its `el` to the dom.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty with Backbone and I'm not entirely happy with this as a solution, but this works: change your `PersonItemView` class to look like:

```
var PersonItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#tpl_person_item').html()),
    initialize: function () {
        this.el = null;
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'remove', this.remove);
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    },
    render: function () {
        console.info("render person:" + this.model.get("name"), this.el);
        if (this.el == null) {
            var el = $(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            this.setElement(el);
        }
        else {
            $(this.el).replaceWith($(this.template(this.model.toJSON())));
        }
        return this;
    }
});
```

Perhaps a better solution would be for `PersonListView.addOne` to create an empty `<li>` element and pass that to the constructor of `PersonItemView`, then `PersonItemView.render` could always just use `replaceWith`.

Answer (score 0):

when you are changing the model only render of the PersonItemView is executed. The function is changing the el of view but not updating the DOM as per your code.

As you are updating DOM only in collection view just render complete collection when change in even single model

```
 var PersonListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addOne);
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.addAll);
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change', this.addAll);
        },
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/pexebojuwe/1/)

Solution 2:
setElement overwrites the el of element, so you are updating the element that is not in DOM. so don't use setElement and just update the same el.

```
 var PersonItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
        render: function () {
            console.info("render person:" + this.model.get("name"));
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON());
            return this;
        }
    });
```

if you want to use setElement make sure you are adding the el to DOM again. which is not happening in your code.

Comment: I have tried to avoid refresh the whole collection view once only one item to be updated.